# Qdrant client scroll filter does not work

Tags: python, langchain, qdrant, qdrantclient

I'm using Qdrant database through its Python client. I need to find entries in the database that have some metadata field set to a certain value (without using vector similarity). I'm trying to do it this way:

```
from qdrant_client.http import models

condition = models.FieldCondition(key="field_name", match=models.MatchValue(value="some_value"))
scroll_filter = models.Filter(must=[condition])
results = client.scroll(collection_name="my_collection", scroll_filter=scroll_filter)
```

I know that there are points that have metadata "field_name=some_value", but the response is `([], None)` no matter what I try. Is there a way to query the database based on metadata only?

(Note: `client.scroll(collection_name="my_collection")` indeed returns results, some of them having the required key/value pair in the metadata. It's the filter that doesn't seem to work.)

EDIT: The problem was that the data was originally inserted using LangChain, which puts the metadata object within the payload. That further means that instead of using `condition=FieldCondition(key="field_name", ...`, one must use `condition=FieldCondition(key="metadata.field_name", ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems to be wrong at the first glance. Would you be able to share the output of the `client.scroll(collection_name="my_collection")` with at least one point matching the criteria? I'd like to verify the structure of the payload.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, that helped. The problem is that the data was inserted using LangChain. That means that metadata is within the payload. Which further means that the fields have to be accessed by `FieldCondition(key="metadata.field_name", ...` instead of `FieldCondition(key="field_name", `.